# code deploy - COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 2

Tags: npm, build

Code Build is failing with the below error.

Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 2

Please help me if anyone is aware of how to fix this issue.

Regards,
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript then your linting errors may cause this type of error. At least in my case it was the linting rules.